# YouTube iFrame embed over top of CSS Hover Submenu in Chrome

Tags: css, flash, iframe, webkit, youtube

I have a standard iframe embed of a video from youtube, I have a CSS Dropmenu that should appear over top of it but is hidden behind the iframe.

Why is this happening? How do I fix it? Ive only seen it doing this in Google Chrome and  Safari so far.

Thanks?

The dropmenu is the same as the one on http://www.no1fitness.co.nz

Answer (score 0):

make sure the `z-index` property of your dropmenu is greater than the one of the iframe

Comment: How do you set the z-index on an iframe?